# Invert Color Ramp in QGIS

Tags: qgis, color-ramp

How do I invert the color ramp in QGIS?  I am using RdYlGn, but I would rather use GnYlRd.  Seems really easy, but I can't seem to find where the invert is.  I am using 1.8.0 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

This feature has been implemented in QGIS 2.2 ([release log](http://changelog.linfiniti.com/qgis/version/21/#97)). It's the checkbox right next to the color ramp:

[image]